# How do i set up a DelayQueue's Delay

Tags: java, queue, delay, timeunit

I'm just starting out coding in java i'm in struggling with setting up a DelayQueue,

I wanted to have it so,

```
DelayQueue queue = new DelayQueue();

If (counter > 0){
queue.offer(Integer, *A custom delay*)
} Else {
queue.offer(Integer, *A different custom delay*)
}
```

I'm just trying to learn all the basics and ive read over the API and cant seem to grasp it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DelayQueue` keeps the elements internally until a certain delay has expired. The elements must implement the interface `java.util.concurrent.Delayed`.

For example I have created a class `DelayedTest` extending Delayed interface. This will implement compareTo and getDelay() method

```
public class A{
    public static void main(String... args){
        DelayQueue  dq=new DelayQueue();
        DeleyedTest ob1=new DeleyedTest(10);
        DeleyedTest ob2=new DeleyedTest(5);
        DeleyedTest ob3=new DeleyedTest(15);

        dq.offer(ob1);
        dq.offer(ob2);
        dq.offer(ob3);

        Iterator itr=dq.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            DeleyedTest dt=(DeleyedTest)itr.next();
            System.out.println(dt.deleyTime);
        }
    }
}
class DeleyedTest implements Delayed{
    public long deleyTime=0;
    DeleyedTest(long deleyTime){
        this.deleyTime=deleyTime;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Delayed ob) {
        if(this.deleyTime<((DeleyedTest)ob).deleyTime){
            return -1;
        }else if(this.deleyTime>((DeleyedTest)ob).deleyTime){
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public long getDelay(TimeUnit unit) {
        return unit.convert(deleyTime-System.currentTimeMillis(),TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS); 
    }

}
```

Result:

```
5
10
15
```

Comment: So for example if the element i was adding to the DelayQueue was cities visited E.G. "Paris" and the delay for every city inside the EU has to be 12 minutes and every city outside the EU has to be 6 minutes. i cannot set the delay with queue.offer(*The City*, *The Delay*) ?

Comment: @Pstie> You can set the `deleyTime`s as you wish just please note that an element is expired when its `getDelay()` method returns a non-positive value. For more information please see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html) and [this](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/de/pxlab/pxl/display/TrackingTarget.java.html).

Comment: Why does `getDelay` always return 0?

Comment: @Paul Sorry, it was a typo, fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

this implementation of `Delayed` is good because:

- implementation of `compareTo()` does not do any class casting, eliminatig the possibility of throwing a `ClassCastException`
- implementation of `compareTo()` uses `Math.min` and `Math.max` functions before casting to `int` in order to properly prevent overflow errors
- implementation of `getDelay()` properly converts the units and actually returns the time remaining

`TestDelay` class implements `Delayed`:

```
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.concurrent.Delayed;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestDelay implements Delayed
{
    public final Long delayMillis;
    public final Long expireTimeMillis;

    public TestDelay(Long delayMillis)
    {
        this.delayMillis = delayMillis;
        this.expireTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()+delayMillis;
    }

    @Override
    public final int compareTo(@NotNull Delayed o)
    {
        long diffMillis = getDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)-o.getDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        diffMillis = Math.min(diffMillis,1);
        diffMillis = Math.max(diffMillis,-1);
        return (int) diffMillis;
    }

    @Override
    public final long getDelay(@NotNull TimeUnit unit)
    {
        long delayMillis = expireTimeMillis-System.currentTimeMillis();
        return unit.convert(delayMillis,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

JUnit unit test showing an example of using the `TestDelay` class:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue;

public class DelayQueueTest
{
    @Test
    public final void generalTest() throws InterruptedException
    {
        DelayQueue<TestDelay> q = new DelayQueue<>();
        q.put(new TestDelay(500L));
        q.put(new TestDelay(2000L));
        q.put(new TestDelay(1000L));
        q.put(new TestDelay(10L));
        q.put(new TestDelay(3000L));
        while (!q.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println(q.take().delayMillis);
        }
    }
}
```

output of `DelayQueueTest`:

[image: unit test output]

Answer (score 7):

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Delayed;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class DelayQueueExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BlockingQueue<DelayedElement> blockingQueue = new DelayQueue<DelayedElement>();

        try {
            blockingQueue
                    .put(new DelayedElement(4000, "Message with delay 4s"));
            blockingQueue
                    .put(new DelayedElement(2000, "Message with delay 2s"));
            blockingQueue
                    .put(new DelayedElement(9000, "Message with delay 9s"));
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        }

        while (!blockingQueue.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                System.out.println(">>" + blockingQueue.take());
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }

        }

    }
}

class DelayedElement implements Delayed {

    private long duration = 0;
    private String message;

    public DelayedElement(long duration, String name) {
        this.duration = System.currentTimeMillis() + duration;
        this.message = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Delayed o) {
        return (int) (this.duration - ((DelayedElement) o).getDuration());
    }

    @Override
    /*
     * Expiration occurs when an element's getDelay(TimeUnit unit) method
     * returns a value less than or equal to zero.
     */
    public long getDelay(TimeUnit unit) {
        long diff = duration - System.currentTimeMillis();
        return unit.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    public long getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(long duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DelayedElement [duration=" + duration + ", message=" + message
                + "]";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "custom delay" classes must return the delay from the `getDelay(TimeUnit timeUnit)` method specified in the `Delayed` interface.
E.g.

```
public class MyClass implements Delayed {
    public long getDelay(TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        long delay = calculateDelaySomehow();
        return delay;
    }
}
```

Note that you also need to provide an implementation for `compareTo()`.

Comment: But how do i associate a delay with the object in the first place? i was under the impression that i could set every object with a different time and they would all could down to 0 (and then below) so for example if i added the integer 21 to the DelayQueue can i set 21 to have a timer of 16 minutes before it is able to be used again. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: You could add a `setDelay()` method in your class for manually setting a static delay, and returning that instead of calculating it.